# Conditional cell naming in Excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

I would like to know if I can name a cell based on whether the cell value beside it is equal to a cell in another table.

Table 1:

[image]

(C37:E41) has Column C with names of departments, Column D with hours spent, and Column E with dollars spent.

Table 2:

[image]

(H57:H62) has the 5 largest expenditures from Table 1 listed in descending order using the `=LARGE(E:E, [1-5])` function in Column H. I would like the cells to the left of Column H (Column G) in Table 2 to display the department name from Column C.

I've tried `=VLOOKUP` but as far as I understand it, the data has to be **directly left** of the cell that is being used as the lookup value.
Other posts with somewhat similar queries have suggested =INDEX, =INDIRECT and/or =MATCH but I did not have any luck setting up a working function.

The only way that I managed to get this working (sort of), was to use =IF(H58=E41, C41) etc. but I couldn't get it to reference the whole table.

Comment: Are there any numbers between the last **Cost** in column E and the bottom of the worksheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more complicated your worksheet becomes with the additional of isolated areas containing non-related information (numerical or otherwise), the more complicated the formulas become to isolate ranges of cells in order to produce true results.

Another method to reference 'islands' of information without having other information areas skew the results is to use [structured tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-F5ED2452-2337-4F71-BED3-C8AE6D2B276E). By allowing you to isolate lookups and cell range references to the cells designated as belonging to the table and discard all other cells on the worksheet this can reduce formula complexity.

To further complicate matters, you are basing your lookups on the results from a [LARGE function](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/large-function-3688ad91-0b0c-43db-8ef8-825a5e5871db). In the case of duplicate amounts, you are going to require the 2nd, 3rd matching dept rather than simply repeating the 1st match. The [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) does a good job of producing these results with cyclic cal;culation without the need of a full-fledged array formula.

---

**[Standard worksheet references (xlA1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qpxsb.png)**

[image: Top 5 with worksheet references]

Since it is unlikely that there is nothing above row 40, all calculations for the top 5 largest values in column E and subsequent lookup returns from columns C and D will start at row 41 (row 40 being the header row of the dept/hours/cost table).

I will assume that there are no numbers below the last cost in column E. That means that there is no subtotal at the bottom of the costs either. This is necessary because then the range of cells that contain the costs can be referred to as:

```
E41:INDEX(E:E, MATCH(1e99, E:E))
```

If there is a single number that does not belong to the dept costs in column E below the valid dept costs in column E then your results will be skewed and any correct return will be coincidental rather than true. If this is the case then the formula(s) will have to have additional calculations.

The formulas in H58:J58 are,

```
=LARGE(E$41:INDEX(E:E, MATCH(1E+99,E:E )), ROW(1:1))
=INDEX(C$41:INDEX(C:C, MATCH(1E+99,$E:$E )), AGGREGATE(15, 6, (ROW(C$41:INDEX(C:C, MATCH(1E+99,$E:$E )))-ROW(C$40))/($E$41:INDEX($E:$E, MATCH(1E+99,$E:$E ))=$H58), COUNTIF($H$58:$H58, $H58)))
=INDEX(D$41:INDEX(D:D, MATCH(1E+99,$E:$E )), AGGREGATE(15, 6, (ROW(D$41:INDEX(D:D, MATCH(1E+99,$E:$E )))-ROW(D$40))/($E$41:INDEX($E:$E, MATCH(1E+99,$E:$E ))=$H58), COUNTIF($H$58:$H58, $H58)))
```

Fill down as necessary.

---

**[Structured table references (xlA1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFNvJ.png)**

[image: Top 5 with table references]

In the above sample image, a table has been created (Insert ► Tables ► Table) and named (context menu Table Tools ► Design ► Properties ► Table Name) **TableDHC**. A **Total row** has been added just to prove that it does not interfere with the results.

The formulas in H58:J58 are now,

```
=LARGE(TableDHC[Cost], ROW(1:1))
=INDEX(TableDHC[Dept], AGGREGATE(15, 6, (ROW(TableDHC[Dept])-ROW(TableDHC[#Headers]))/(TableDHC[Cost]=$H58), COUNTIF($H$58:$H58, $H58)))
=INDEX(TableDHC[Hours], AGGREGATE(15, 6, (ROW(TableDHC[Hours])-ROW(TableDHC[#Headers]))/(TableDHC[Cost]=$H58), COUNTIF($H$58:$H58, $H58)))
```

Fill down as necessary.

---

Whether the structured table references help you to simplify the process or not is strictly up to the user. If you are aware of both methods, you can make a choice. If there were numbers below E59 that were going to demand more complicated worksheet-style formulas, I would likely go the structured tables route.

---

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer @Jeeped. There is quite a bit of information below the last row in E (different facilities) but I can certainly work with what you have provided.